# netsh wlan show profiles name="name" key=clear"

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, netsh

I wrote in cmd with administrator rights this "netsh wlan show  profiles  name="name" key=clear" but I dont see the password of the wifi, only  "key content: available". Anybody know whats happend? and how could I solve this problem?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to clear this wifi profile information and reconnect? Then use the netsh command to check again. Also you could use the powershell command and UI setting to check if the password will be displayed.https://appuals.com/how-to-view-your-wireless-network-security-key-or-password-on-windows-10/

Comment: @daidai The problem is that I don't know the password, my laptop was broken and I can only read the xml from the hard drive, where are the passwords but encrypted, and I want to know this password.

Comment: Take a look at this [netsh-wlan-show-profiles-command](https://superuser.com/questions/1220113/facing-an-issue-in-running-netsh-wlan-show-profiles-command?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I realised I was using a Network Adapter. I disconnected the wifi adapter and then it worked. The password showed up in cmd and I wasn't even using cmd as Admin. Hope this helps you either way.

Viper.