# How to show keys in netsh without mentioning the name parameter

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, netsh, internet-security

Queria saber se no netsh show profiles key=clear,ao invés de colocar o ssid de cada rede para ver o "Conteúdo da chave", poderia mostrar de uma forma geral. Já tentei usar o "*" no name,mas não deu certo.

--

I want to know if in netsh show profiles key=clear, instead of putting the SSID of each network to see the "Key Content", I could show it in a general way. I already tried using "*" in the name, but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at this [netsh-wlan-show-profiles-command](https://superuser.com/questions/1220113/facing-an-issue-in-running-netsh-wlan-show-profiles-command?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list saved passwords without providing the **SSID** individually for each profile, I recommend using a double **`for`** loop that runs through each profile by printing only the saved password:

> - For Command Line

For US/EN system:

---

```
@for /f tokens^=2*delims^=^: %i in ('netsh wlan show profiles')do @set "_ssid=%~i" && @for /f tokens^=2*delims^=: %I in ('cmd/v/c netsh wlan show profiles "!_ssid:~1!" key^=clear^|findstr /vi "absent"^|findstr "Key"')do @echo/%I
```

---

For PT/BR system:

```
@for /f tokens^=2*delims^=^: %i in ('netsh wlan show profiles')do @set "_ssid=%~i" && @for /f tokens^=2*delims^=: %I in ('cmd/v/c netsh wlan show profiles "!_ssid:~1!" key^=clear^|findstr /vi "ausente"^|findstr /i "da.chave"')do @echo/%I
```

---

> - For **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** files:

For US/EN system:

---

```
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=2*delims^=^: %%i in ('netsh wlan show profiles')do set "_ssid=%%~i" && (
for /f tokens^=2*delims^=^: %%I in ('cmd/v/c netsh wlan show profiles "!_ssid:~1!" key^=clear^|findstr /vi "absent"^|findstr "Key"
')do echo/%%I )
```

---

For PT/BR system:

```
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=2*delims^=^: %%i in ('netsh wlan show profiles')do set "_ssid=%%~i" && (
for /f tokens^=2*delims^=^: %%I in ('cmd/v/c netsh wlan show profiles "!_ssid:~1!" key^=clear^|findstr /vi "ausente"^|findstr /i "da.chave"
')do echo/%%I )
```

---

---

For those who want to print **`SSID`** and ad password **`%%~i`** in:

```
 ')do echo/%%~i :%%I )
```